# selecting table colums names from the second colum onwards in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen this code for retrieving all columns names in a table  in mysql

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

My problem is i needed to select from second column onward. does anyone have an idea.

Comment: just add an offset

Comment: actually i have tried initiating $i=1; then in the fetch loop i tried starting from $column[$i] but am not getting it

Comment: This kind of problem is often indicative of poor design

Comment: no, just part of getting  to know deeper

Answer (score 3):

You just need to mention "ORDINAL_POSITION".

```
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
 AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename' 
 AND `ORDINAL_POSITION` > 1;
```

Hope this helps.